# print out once in a 2d-array at java

Tags: java

how can i just print out the j only once and not three times?

```
public static void berechneSterneProSpalte(char[][] arr) {
    for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

char[][] bsp3 = {{'*', 'a', '*', 'a'}, {'*', '*', '*', 'b'}, {'B', 'c', '0', 'c'}}; // Beispiel aus Aufgabenteil b
    System.out.println("Aufgabenteil b: ");
    berechneSterneProSpalte(bsp3);
```

Result:
Aufgabenteil b:
0123
0123
0123

Comment: don't put it in the outer loop

Comment: what u mean? it is in the inner loop

Comment: yeah but the inner loop is inside another one

Comment: yeah i know, it is a 2d array, so i need 2 loops

Comment: the first loop for the row, the second for the column

Comment: what is the purpose of your code

Comment: What is that code even supposed to do? The method is called "Calculate stars per column" (in german) but honestly you don't calculate anything in that method and do nothing with the stars. All you do is loop over your 2D array and print out the indexes of each row....I really fail to see how that method does even remotely what its name suggests

Comment: i have a array like above and i need to count the * every column

Comment: Instead of printing `j` put it into a StringBuilder object then print that after the outer loop

Comment: im not at the point to calucate or to count...im looking how i can print out the columns, there after i can count the *

Comment: "im looking how i can print out the columns" <- And how would printing `0123` once do that exactly? If you want to print the columns, shouldn't you expect the result `**B a*c **0 abc`?

Comment: its solved, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a boolean which determines if you already have it displayed, like this:

```
public static void berechneSterneProSpalte(char[][] arr) {
    boolean isDisplayed=false;
    for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
           if(!isDisplayed){
             System.out.print(j);
           }
        }
        isDisplayed=true;
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you needed?:

```
public static void berechneSterneProSpalte(char[][] arr) {
    for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        int starCount = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            if(arr[i][j]=='*'){
               starCount++;
            }
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.println("Number of Stars = " + starCount);
    }
}

char[][] bsp3 = {{'*', 'a', '*', 'a'}, {'*', '*', '*', 'b'}, {'B', 'c', '0', 'c'}}; // Beispiel aus Aufgabenteil b
    System.out.println("Aufgabenteil b: ");
    berechneSterneProSpalte(bsp3);
```

Comment: Thanks to the question asking about the exact objective of the question. Credits of this answer if any go to that comment

Comment: this is what i got, it counts the stars for every row, i need to count now the start every columns ^-^

`public static void berechneSterneProZeile(char[][] arr) {
  for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   int count = 0;
   for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    if(arr[i][j] == '*') {
     count++;
    }
   }
   System.out.println(i + ": " + count);
  }
 }`